# Prove that no set of $n$ points can be triangulated in more than $2^{n \choose 2}$ ways.

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, computational-geometry, triangulation

Prove that no set of $n$ points can be triangulated in more than $2^{n \choose 2}$ ways.

So I am really confused about the argument. We have two choices to triangulate 4 sided polygon. 
[image]

So the natural upper bound would be $2^{n \choose 4}$. I am not sure why we can reduce it to choosing only 2 points, instead of 4...

Problem is from Computational Geometry De Berg.

Comment: If you have $n$ labeled vertices, how many [graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) can be formed with them?  Is a triangulation a graph?  What then is an obvious upper bound on the number of triangulations as a result?

Comment: As an aside, the bound of $2^{\binom{n}{2}}$ is tight*er* for all $n\geq 7$ than $2^{\binom{n}{4}}$ (*despite $2^{\binom{n}{2}}>2^{\binom{n}{4}}$ for your specific example of $n=4$*), but it is by no means a *tight* upper bound.  There are many graphs which are not triangulations.  For a more exact result on the number of triangulations, read about [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have ${n \choose 2}$ pairs of vertices and for each pair we can connect or not connect thus we have $2^{n \choose 2}$ ways to connect.

Comment: Sorry, I think I don't get this.. can you please elaborate?

Comment: @YohanRoth we cannot have more than $2^{n \choose 2}$ graphs with simply connected vertices and the triangulated graphs are a subset of this.

Comment: @ can you explain the argument why we cannot have more than this number of graphs... sorry I am dumb person :P

Comment: @YohanRoth It a simple combinatorics fact descendig from the rule of product  (look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product). To figure out consider the simple case of n=3, we know that the tringulated graph is 1 but all the possible graphs are $2^3=8$.